# The remainder when $( \sum_{k=1}^5 { ^{20} \mathrm C (2k-1) } )^6$ is divided by 11, is :

Tags: combinatorics

How do I approach this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle S =\binom{20}{1}+\binom{20}{3}+\binom{20}{5}+\binom{20}{7} +\binom{20}{9}\cdots (1)$

$\displaystyle S =\binom{20}{9}+\binom{20}{7}+\binom{20}{5}+\binom{20}{3}+\binom{20}{1}$

Using $\displaystyle \binom{n}{r}=\binom{n}{n-r}$

$\displaystyle S =\binom{20}{11}+\binom{20}{13}+\binom{20}{15}+\binom{20}{17}+\binom{20}{19}\cdots (2)$

Add $(1)$ and $(2)$

$\displaystyle 2S =\sum^{10}_{k=1}\binom{20}{2k-1}=2^{19}$

$$\displaystyle S =2^{18}$$

We have to calculate remainder when $\bigg(2^{18}\bigg)^6=2^{108}$ is divided by $11$

Now $2^{3}\cdot \bigg(2^{5}\bigg)^{21}=8\cdot (32)^{21}$

$=-8\cdot (1-33)^{21}=-8+M(11)=3-11+M(11)=3+M'(11)$

So remainder is $3$ when $2^{108}$ is divided by $11$

Where $M(11)$ and $M'(11)$ is Multiple of $11$

Comment: Thank you so much...

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^5\binom{20}{2k-1}\right)^6=262144^6\equiv3^6\equiv3.$$

Comment: And here I was, stumped on what $C$ could possibly mean ;)

Comment: Sorry I was not able to the code for it

Comment: @Aayush We don't nee any code here. Just use $\binom{20}{1}=20,$ $\binom{20}{3}=\frac{20\cdot19\cdot18}{3!}$...

Comment: @Michael , is there no other way than calculating that inside the bracket fully.....As for time was given 2 mins.....

Comment: So , I do not think this way is convenient

Comment: @Aayush There is, of course. But for which we need to use complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left[\binom{20}{1}+\binom{20}{3}+\binom{20}{5}+\binom{20}{7}+\binom{20}{9}\right]^6=(20+1140+15504+77520+167960)^6\equiv 
(-2+7+5+3+1)^6\equiv3^6\equiv3\mod{11}$$

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, the expression inside the brackets is a quarter of $2^{20}$. 
It is a half of the sum for all odd $q$; and the sum for all odd $q$ equals the sum for all even $q$.
To prove that, expand $(1-1)^{20}$ using the binomial expansion.